# my @media CSS selector isn't working, When I change the screen size, nothing happens

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a burger menu button appear in the right hand corner of the screen when it gets to a certain size (960px) but when I minimize the window nothing shows up..

index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>scroll website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">  
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Navbar section -->
    <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar__container">
            <a href="#home" id="navbar__logo">COLOR</a>
            <div class="navbar__toggle" id="mobile-menu">
                <span class="bar"></span>
                <span class="bar"></span>
                <span class="bar"></span>
            </div> 
            <ul class="navbar__menu">
                <li class="nav__item">
                    <a href="#home" class="navbar__links" id="home-page">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav__item">
                    <a href="#about" class="navbar__links" id="about-page">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav__item">
                    <a href="#services" class="navbar__links" id="services-page">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li class="navbar__btn">
                    <a href="#sign-up" class="button" id="signup">Sign Up</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
        
</body>
</html>
```

style.css : (if you comment out 'top: -1000px' in the media query, the menu screen will drop down)

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Kumbh Sans', sans-serif;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.navbar {
    background: #131313;
    height: 80px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 998;
}

.navbar__container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 80px;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 50px;
}

#navbar__logo {
    background-color: #ff8177;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #ff0844 0%, #ffb199 100%);
    background-size: 100%;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.navbar__menu {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    list-style: none;
}

.navbar__item {
    height: 80px;
}

.navbar__links {
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 125px;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 100%;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.navbar__btn {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    width: 100%;
}

.button {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius:4px;
    background: #833ab4;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #fcb845, #fd1d1d, #833ab4);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #fcb845, #fd1d1d, #833ab4);
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}


.navbar__links:hover {
    color: #9518fc;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}



@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    .navbar__container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        height: 80px;
        z-index: 1;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 1300px;
        padding: 0; 
    }

    .navbar__menu {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto;
        margin: 0;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: -1000px;
        opacity: 1;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
        z-index: -1;
        background: #131313;
        
    }

    .navbar__menu.active {
        background: #131313;
        top: 100%;
        opacity: 1;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
        z-index: 99;
        height: 60vh;
        font-size: 1.6rem;
    }

    #navbar__logo {
        padding-left: 25px;
    }

    #navbar__toggle .bar {
        width: 25px;
        height: 3px;
        margin: 5px auto;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        background: #fff
    }

    .navbar__item {
        width: 100%
    }

    .navbar__links {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 2rem;
        width: 100%;
        display: table;
    }

    .navbar__btn {
        padding-bottom: 2rem;
    }

    .buttom {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 80%;
        height: 80px;
        margin: 0;
    }

    #mobile-menu {
        position: absolute;
        top: 20%;
        right: 5%;
        transform: translate(5%, 20%);
    }

    .navbar__toggle .bar {
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

   
}
```

Please help, I feel like I've tried everything and nothing works.

Comment: Try removing ``screen and``

Comment: Try providing a [mcve] (emphasis on the minimal)

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it does not appear

```
<div class="navbar__toggle" id="mobile-menu">
   <span class="bar"></span>
   <span class="bar"></span>
   <span class="bar"></span>
</div>
```

no information to appear here.

You can add an icon or a text inside, or you can fill in the spans.
Remember that the main color of the texts is black, you may not see it because you are black on your background. You will need to color it.

Comment: how do I add an Icon? I'm not sure what you mean. Can you tell me exactly what to do ?

Comment: Put something within the span: `<span class="bar">SOMETHING</span>`

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually doing anything as of yet. Add a navbar, then add a script. I used your classlist to toggle in this scenario:

```js
document.getElementById('mobile-menu').addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  this.classList.toggle('open');
  const navbar = document.querySelector('.navbar__menu');
  navbar.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Kumbh Sans', sans-serif;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.navbar {
  background: #131313;
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 998;
}

.navbar__container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 80px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 50px;
}

#navbar__logo {
  background-color: #ff8177;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #ff0844 0%, #ffb199 100%);
  background-size: 100%;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.navbar__menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar__item {
  height: 80px;
}

.navbar__links {
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 125px;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.navbar__btn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #833ab4;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #fcb845, #fd1d1d, #833ab4);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #fcb845, #fd1d1d, #833ab4);
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.navbar__links:hover {
  color: #9518fc;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

@media (max-width: 960px) {
  .navbar__container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 80px;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1300px;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .navbar__menu {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1000px;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    z-index: -1;
    background: #131313;
  }
  .navbar__menu.active {
    background: #131313;
    top: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    z-index: 99;
    height: 60vh;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
  }
  #navbar__logo {
    padding-left: 25px;
  }
  #navbar__toggle .bar {
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    background: #fff
  }
  .navbar__item {
    width: 100%
  }
  .navbar__links {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2rem;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
  }
  .navbar__btn {
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
  }
  .buttom {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 0;
  }
  #mobile-menu span:nth-child(1) {
    top: 0px;
  }
  #mobile-menu span:nth-child(2),
  #mobile-menu span:nth-child(3) {
    top: 18px;
  }
  #mobile-menu span:nth-child(4) {
    top: 36px;
  }
  #mobile-menu.open span:nth-child(1) {
    top: 18px;
    width: 0%;
    left: 50%;
  }
  #mobile-menu {
    width: 60px;
    height: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    right: 5%;
    transform: translate(5%, 20%);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #mobile-menu span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 9px;
    width: 100%;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 9px;
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  }
  #mobile-menu.open span:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  #mobile-menu.open span:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  #mobile-menu.open span:nth-child(4) {
    top: 18px;
    width: 0%;
    left: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<body>
  <!-- Navbar section -->
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar__container">
      <a href="#home" id="navbar__logo">COLOR</a>
      <div class="navbar__toggle" id="mobile-menu">
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
      </div>
      <ul class="navbar__menu">
        <li class="nav__item">
          <a href="#home" class="navbar__links" id="home-page">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav__item">
          <a href="#about" class="navbar__links" id="about-page">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav__item">
          <a href="#services" class="navbar__links" id="services-page">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar__btn">
          <a href="#sign-up" class="button" id="signup">Sign Up</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

</body>
```

Full code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>scroll website</title>
  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: 'Kumbh Sans', sans-serif;
      scroll-behavior: smooth;
    }
    
    .navbar {
      background: #131313;
      height: 80px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      font-size: 1.2rem;
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
      z-index: 998;
    }
    
    .navbar__container {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      height: 80px;
      z-index: 1;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 1300px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 0 50px;
    }
    
    #navbar__logo {
      background-color: #ff8177;
      background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #ff0844 0%, #ffb199 100%);
      background-size: 100%;
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
      -moz-background-clip: text;
      -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
      -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      cursor: pointer;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 2rem;
    }
    
    .navbar__menu {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      list-style: none;
    }
    
    .navbar__item {
      height: 80px;
    }
    
    .navbar__links {
      color: #fff;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      width: 125px;
      text-decoration: none;
      height: 100%;
      transition: all 0.3s ease;
    }
    
    .navbar__btn {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      padding: 0 1rem;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .button {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 10px 20px;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      border-radius: 4px;
      background: #833ab4;
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #fcb845, #fd1d1d, #833ab4);
      background: linear-gradient(to right, #fcb845, #fd1d1d, #833ab4);
      color: #fff;
      transition: all 0.3s ease;
    }
    
    .navbar__links:hover {
      color: #9518fc;
      transition: all 0.3s ease;
    }
    
    @media (max-width: 960px) {
      .navbar__container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        height: 80px;
        z-index: 1;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 1300px;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .navbar__menu {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto;
        margin: 0;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: -1000px;
        opacity: 1;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
        z-index: -1;
        background: #131313;
      }
      .navbar__menu.active {
        background: #131313;
        top: 100%;
        opacity: 1;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
        z-index: 99;
        height: 60vh;
        font-size: 1.6rem;
      }
      #navbar__logo {
        padding-left: 25px;
      }
      #navbar__toggle .bar {
        width: 25px;
        height: 3px;
        margin: 5px auto;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        background: #fff
      }
      .navbar__item {
        width: 100%
      }
      .navbar__links {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 2rem;
        width: 100%;
        display: table;
      }
      .navbar__btn {
        padding-bottom: 2rem;
      }
      .buttom {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 80%;
        height: 80px;
        margin: 0;
      }
      #mobile-menu span:nth-child(1) {
        top: 0px;
      }
      #mobile-menu span:nth-child(2),
      #mobile-menu span:nth-child(3) {
        top: 18px;
      }
      #mobile-menu span:nth-child(4) {
        top: 36px;
      }
      #mobile-menu.open span:nth-child(1) {
        top: 18px;
        width: 0%;
        left: 50%;
      }
      #mobile-menu {
        width: 60px;
        height: 45px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 20%;
        right: 5%;
        transform: translate(5%, 20%);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
        transition: .5s ease-in-out;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      #mobile-menu span {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        height: 9px;
        width: 100%;
        background: white;
        border-radius: 9px;
        opacity: 1;
        left: 0;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
        transition: .25s ease-in-out;
      }
      #mobile-menu.open span:nth-child(2) {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
        transform: rotate(45deg);
      }
      #mobile-menu.open span:nth-child(3) {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        transform: rotate(-45deg);
      }
      #mobile-menu.open span:nth-child(4) {
        top: 18px;
        width: 0%;
        left: 50%;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Navbar section -->
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar__container">
      <a href="#home" id="navbar__logo">COLOR</a>
      <div class="navbar__toggle" id="mobile-menu">
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
      </div>
      <ul class="navbar__menu">
        <li class="nav__item">
          <a href="#home" class="navbar__links" id="home-page">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav__item">
          <a href="#about" class="navbar__links" id="about-page">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav__item">
          <a href="#services" class="navbar__links" id="services-page">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar__btn">
          <a href="#sign-up" class="button" id="signup">Sign Up</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

</body>

<script>
  document.getElementById('mobile-menu').addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    this.classList.toggle('open');
    const navbar = document.querySelector('.navbar__menu');
    navbar.classList.toggle('active');
  });
</script>

</html>
```